# Combobox já selecionado com valor do banco de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, combobox

Tenho alguns combobox na área de edição de informações do usuário e preciso puxar o dado já selecionado anteriormente pelo usuário na hora cadastro. Tentei fazer com o foreach mas não funcionou.

```html
 <div class="form-group col-md-5" >
      <label for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
      <select name="sexo_cliente" id="sexo_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
         <option selected disabled="">Sexo</option>
         <?php 
            require_once "api/conexao.php";

            try {
                $prepared3 = $conexao_pdo->prepare("select * from sexo");
                $prepared3->execute();
                $result3 = $prepared3->fetchAll();

                    foreach($result3 as $resultado3) { 
                        echo "<option value='". $resultado3["cod"] ."'>". $resultado3["sexo"] ."</option>";
                    }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "<option></option>";
            }   

            ?>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode resolver isso verificando o valor cadastrado pelo usuário e comparando o mesmo com os valores que serão colocados nas options, definindo como selected (option marcada por default) o sexo do usuário a ser editado.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-5" >
    <label for="inputSexo">Sexo</label>
    <select name="sexo_cliente" id="sexo_cliente" class="form-control" disabled>
        <option selected disabled="">Sexo</option>
            <?php 
                require_once "api/conexao.php";

                try {
                    $prepared3 = $conexao_pdo->prepare("select * from sexo");
                    $prepared3->execute();
                    $result3 = $prepared3->fetchAll();

                        foreach($result3 as $resultado3) { 
                            // $varSexoUsuario é a variavel com valor do sexo do usuario
                            $selected = ($resultado3["cod"] == $varSexoUsuario) ? 'selected' : '';
                            echo "<option value='". $resultado3["cod"] ."' ".$selected.">". $resultado3["sexo"] ."</option>";
                        }

                } catch (PDOException $e) {
                    echo "<option></option>";
                }   
        ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Imagino que essa variavel venha preenchida com o atributo do usuario que está tentando editar...

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigada!!